# Route not working on Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to learn Ember by following the instructions from their guides. I've created a route called favorites (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/concepts/naming-conventions/) but I can access the url http://localhost:port/favorites.

Am I missing something?

Here is my router.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('favorites');
});

export default Router;
```

And my favorites.hbs:

```
<ul>
  {{#each favorites as |item|}}
    <li>{{item.name}} - {{item.email}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I've pushed my project to this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/julianonunes/EmberTest).

Comment: what link you want to know?

Comment: I am assuming you are following steps from here : http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#getting-started), if so then after running "ember server" you should be able to access it at http://localhost:4200/favorites

Comment: I following the steps from http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/concepts/naming-conventions/ and I'm running "ember server" to test in the browser. If I go to http://localhost:4200/favorites the output is the same as the one from http://localhost:4200/.

Comment: what does your controller and route look like, can you add those code in there too. I just created a blank app which just renders some text(not using model hook), and it worked for me - so I am assuming the issue might be in the route or the controller.

Comment: Does changing `{{#each favorites as |item|}}` to `{{#each model as |item|}}` help?

Comment: I had to add the `{{outlet}}` helper like @Kitler mentioned, but I also had to  make the change @Knightsy posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `{{outlet}}` helper in your `application.hbs` template.

> Ember.js will render the favorites template into the {{outlet}} in the application template. It will set an instance of the controller:favorites as the controller for the template.

Comment: just a simple question. How can I use a different template file (instead of application.hbs)? Suppose that I want an admin.hbs to be the base layout for the administration dashboard.

Comment: Everything goes under the application template, if you want `admin.hbs` to be the base define the route as such `this.route('admin', { path: '/admin', resetNamespace: true }, function() {});`, and then have the application template only contain an `{{outlet}}`.